# Terminating instance with AWS auto scaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have no problem spinning up an instance using the time scheduling feature of AWS auto scale:

```
as-put-scheduled-update-group-action Start
    --auto-scaling-group MyASG
    --min-size 1
    --max-size 1
    --recurrence "20 15 * * *"
```

But when I try and schedule this instance to be terminated, nothing happens:

```
as-put-scheduled-update-group-action Stop
    --auto-scaling-group MyASG
    --min-size 0
    --max-size 0
    --recurrence "50 15 * * *"
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks Steffen. A delay wasn't an issue, it might have been a case of me trying more than 4 schedules in the one day though! Just for completeness, are these the only steps necessary to spin up one instance and then take it back down a few minutes later:

```
as-create-launch-config MyLC
    --image-id ami-f2191786
    --instance-type t1.micro
as-create-auto-scaling-group MyASG
    --launch-configuration MyLC
    --availability-zones eu-west-1a
    --min-size 0
    --max-size 1
as-put-scheduled-update-group-action Start
    --auto-scaling-group MyASG
    --min-size 1
    --max-size 1
    --desired-capacity 1
    --recurrence "16 10 7 5 2"
as-put-scheduled-update-group-action Stop
    --auto-scaling-group MyASG
    --min-size 0
    --max-size 0
    --desired-capacity 0
    --recurrence "2 10 7 5 2"
```

Comment: My guess is that you just updated the Autoscaling group and not the Trigger. So update the autoscaling trigger and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your [Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) usage as such is correct: While the respective example for [Scale Based on a Schedule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/schedule_time.html) is using the `--desired-capacity` parameter rather than adjusting `--max-size` (see section *Create a Schedule for Scaling Actions*), it should work regardless indeed - I've just replayed your example to ensure it does and it works just fine for me.

Maybe you are just experiencing the implied API delays, see section *Programming Considerations for Scheduled Actions*:

> - A scheduled action generally executes within seconds. **However, the action may be delayed for up to two minutes from the scheduled start
>     time**. Because Auto Scaling executes actions within an Auto Scaling
>     group in the order they are specified, scheduled actions with
>     scheduled start times close to each other may take longer to execute. *[emphasis mine]*

In this regard it's worth noting that the scheduled action has been visible within seconds via `as-describe-scaling-activities --auto-scaling-group MyASG` indeed, but the ongoing termination of the instance became visible about ~30 seconds later in my case, so you might want to check via the API/CLI to see whether the action executed successfully - accordingly this would also be the approach to see details about any errors that might have happened in case.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, I updated my question, could you confirm that my new approach is correct? I can't run another schedule today (already tested 4 schedules) so can't confirm it for myself